# Associate static FQDN with Azure Managed Instance

Tags: azure, azure-sql-database, azure-sql-managed-instance, azure-dns, azure-managed-database

I have a Azure managed instance that has a host name as **`yourdb.<DNS-ZONE>.database.windows.net`** . I Whenever this managed instance is newly created I have to update this host name in every connection string.

Is there a way which allows to have a static FQDN for managed instance?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To use the custom DNS, Azure SQL Managed Instance must be deployed within an Azure virtual network (VNet). Check [Configure a custom DNS for Azure SQL Managed Instance](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-sql/managed-instance/custom-dns-configure).

Also, check the scenarios which is suitable for FQDN in the following [link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/virtual-network/virtual-networks-name-resolution-for-vms-and-role-instances#name-resolution-that-uses-your-own-dns-server).